# DateTime parse - unexpected result

Tags: c#, .net, datetime

I have following code:

```cs
string date = "1.10.2020";
DateTime dt;
if (DateTime.TryParse(date, new CultureInfo("hu-HU"), DateTimeStyles.None, out dt))
{

}
```

Because the hungarian short date format is "yyyy.MM.dd", I expect, that the TryParse() result to false. But the result is true, and the DateTime is "10. January 2020".

Can I prevent that the parse uses a "fallback" and returns true?

Comment: Use [`DateTime.TryParseExact()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.tryparseexact?view=net-5.0)

Comment: TryParseExact could be useful here, you specify the format and it has to match exactly, otherwise it will fail

Comment: _"the hungarian short date format is `yyyy.MM.dd`"_ +1 for your country using the superior date format as its cultural default (I'll allow the unusual `.` separator)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [`DateTime.TryParseExact()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.tryparseexact?view=net-5.0#System_DateTime_TryParseExact_System_String_System_String_System_IFormatProvider_System_Globalization_DateTimeStyles_System_DateTime__) method -

```cs
string date = "1.10.2020";
DateTime dt;
if (DateTime.TryParseExact(date, "yyyy.MM.dd", new CultureInfo("hu-HU"), DateTimeStyles.None, out dt))
{
    //
}
```

Comment: Thank you all. The TryParseExact did I missed.